# I am attempting to add a user but the terminal seems to crash

Tags: 15.04, adduser

I'm trying to add a user using: `sudo -s adduser leslie`

I get this result: `[sudo] password for david:`

From then on I type but nothing appears. I need to setup the Sharing preferences. I'm using Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: Just enter your password and hit the return key. `sudo` always asks for passwords with terminal echo turned of, that means you don't see anything, not even stars. This is a security feature to prevent people from finding out you password's length by looking at your screen or a log. You may set it up to show stars instead of nothing though, but I would not recommend this.

Comment: the -s option isn't needed for that operation (additionally, though it wont cause any problems, ..2 less characters to type)

Comment: That's the problem. I go to type in the password and nothing appears.